# Preposition help required: which sentence is correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

I would like to know which of the following sentences is grammatically correct and why?

> Nadeem has been living **along** his family in Murree for ten year

or

> Nadeem has been living **with** his family in Murree for ten year

Comment: the second one, always. "living along his family" is always incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would be grammatically correct and highly idiomatic is

> Nadeem has been living with his family in Murree for ten years

Notice "years" rather than "year."

What would also be grammatically correct but not so common is

> Nadeem has been living alongside his family in Murree for ten years

That has a slightly different meaning than the first sentence has. The first strongly implies coresidence. The second implies "close by" and with some degree of intimacy but almost certainly not coresidence. So which sentence is the correct one depends on what meaning is intended.

"Along his family" is just wrong. And "alongside" is not common in modern American English; it would probably be replaced by "close to."